# density of primes $p$ such that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ both have roots mod $p$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be irreducible polynomials over rationals. I know that to find the density of the primes $p$ such that (say) $f(x)$ has a root mod $p$ can be found using Chebotarev density theorem, looking at the density of elements with fixed points in the Galois group of $f(x)$. (Thinking of the Galois group embedded in $S_d$, where d is the degree of $f$) I was wondering what is the general way of doing this when we're given two polynomials $f$ and $g$, and if we try to find the density of primes such that both $f$ and $g$ have roots mod $p$. Should we somehow look at the compositum of the splitting fields of $f$ and $g$?

Comment: yes. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @mercio I don't know how though.

Comment: There is an example here: https://mathoverflow.net/q/165606 (notice that it this question, $p \mid y^4+1$ iff $X^4+1$ splits mod $p$ iff $p$ splits in $\Bbb Q(\zeta_8)$ iff $p \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ (for a prime $p > 2$).

Comment: Let $a$ be a root of $f$, $b$ a root of $g$. Pick some algebraic integer $c$ such that $\Bbb Q(c) = \Bbb Q(a, b)$, so that there are some $U, V \in \Bbb Q[X]$ with $a = U(c), b = V(c)$. 
$\hspace{1cm}$

Now $f \circ U$ and $g \circ V$ both have the minimal polynomial $P \in \Bbb Z[X]$ of $c$ as factors.
We conclude that if $P(X)$ has a root $z$ mod $p$, then $f(X)$ has the root $U(z)$ mod $p$ and $g(X)$ has the root $V(z)$ mod $p$.$\hspace{1cm}$

Thus, Chebotarev's theorem gives you a lower density for the set of primes such that $f$ and $g$ both have roots mod $p$.